# There was a strange sorting

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a two ArrayList and I store music title here

ArrayList - A

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Data>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
        return o1.getAlbum().compareTo(o2.getAlbum()); // get Type String
    }
});
```

ArrayList - B

```
`Collections.sort(song_list_data); // String
```

I saved each data and sorted it out. It looked fine, but when I looked at it in detail, I got a little problem.

There are two pieces of data in the saved song, "Paris" and "Paris Nights / New York Mornings."

I think the normal order is

> Paris
>
> Paris Nights / New York Mornings

So ArrayList - A keeps this order.

However, ArrayList-B

> Paris Nights / New York Mornings
>
> Paris

It is saved in this order  So the title and the actual data is different,

Most of song title the others are fine, but I do not know why this happened;

Comment: Are you sure that you are sorting after adding the data to the list and there are no modifications afterwards?

Comment: All data has been sorted after adding it to the data list and has not been modified.

Comment: Where does this data come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example you've given uses the comparability of the album names.

```
o1.compareTo(o2);
```

is not the same thing as

```
o1.getAlbumName().compareTo(o2.getAlbumName());
```

`Collections.sort(song_list_data)` will use the natural ordering of the `Data` object itself, whereas your custom `Comparator`, which delegates to the album name, will use the second.